# What causes Neo4j error: Illegal char <:> at index 3

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///‪C:/Users/SESA472806/Desktop/CustomerTagDB_IOAssgiment_M91_with_IO_Allocation_LAST_4.csv" as line
with line, line.`Plant Name` as plnt

Call{    
     with line, plnt
     merge(p:Plant{Name : plnt})
     SET p.validCount ='null', p.projectName = 'Null', p.projectId = 'Null', p.progress ='Null', p.modelValidCount = 'Null',     p.modelinstabceCount = 'Null', p.modelBadCount = 'Null', p.isPropagated = 'Null' , p.isCustomerLoaded = 'Null', p.isControlLoaded = 'Null', p.instanceCount = 'Null', p.CutomerDbPath = 'Null', p.ControlDbPath = 'Null', p.badCount = 'Null', p.AmlPath = 'Null' , p.allProjectPath = 'Null'
     return p
}
return p
```

##### ERROR

```
Illegal char <:> at index 3: /‪C:/Users/SESA472806/Desktop/CustomerTagDB_IOAssgiment_M91_with_IO_Allocation_LAST_4.csv ? What is the error in neo4j
```

I don't understand the error. I have used the same code before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Windows, so I can't test your query as it is.

I do have two different theories, though.

There is a security restriction that prevents LOAD CSV from reading from any directory on the local system, but only things under the import folder. It might be that you used to use an older version that didn't have this security restriction before.

This is controlled by this config in neo4j.conf: 
`server.directories.import=import`

Remove or comment it out to get access to the entire file system (but please consider the security implications of that).

If that is not the case, it could be because you have `:` in the column names of the CSV.

This was fixed in Neo4j 5.5.0. Now this works if the header entry also specifies a property type, e.g. `my-key:with-colons:string`

Comment: yes , I have checked the config file it is there

Comment: Is the problem fixed by removing it from the config?